# ERROR : HTTP Status 500 - org.apache.jasper.JasperException, root cause : java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, web-applications

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page     /ShopLoginCheck2.jsp at line 60

57:         <br> You have entered the wrong credentials!
58:         <br> Press any key to go back to the Login page
59:         <%
60:         String takeIn = sc.next();
61:         session.invalidate();
62:         response.sendRedirect("WelcomeShop.jsp");
63:     }
```

In the above code, I am not able to proceed because of the shown error.

Any suggestions to get rid of it?

Am adding more code as asked :

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String s_id_string=(String)request.getParameter("s_id");
int s_id=0;
if(s_id_string !=null)
{
s_id = Integer.parseInt(s_id_string);
}
String s_name=(String)request.getParameter("s_name");
String s_password=(String)request.getParameter("s_password");
Statement stmt1 = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs1 = stmt1.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM ShopSystem.Shop where s_id='"+s_id+"'     AND s_name='"+s_name+"' AND s_password='"+s_password+"'");
    if(rs1.next())
    {   
        if((s_id == rs1.getInt("s_id")) && (s_name.equals(rs1.getString("s_name"))) &&     (s_password.equals(rs1.getString("s_password"))))
        {                           
            session = request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("s_id", s_id);
            session.setAttribute("s_name", s_name);
            session.setAttribute("s_password", s_password);
            response.sendRedirect("ShopMenu3.jsp");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        %>
        <br> You have entered the wrong credentials!
        <br> Press any key to go back to the Login page
        <%
        String takeIn = sc.next();
        session.invalidate();
        response.sendRedirect("WelcomeShop.jsp");
    }
sc.close();
```

And no I dnt intend to use takeIn in any way.
sc is a Scanner object

Comment: post your code . stack traces alone wont help

Comment: `sc.next();` where you defined `sc` ?

Comment: Do you intend to use the `takeIn` variable anywhere?

Comment: And no I dnt intend to use takeIn in any way

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line `String takeIn = sc.next();` as you don't intend to use the returned value from this method call. The error is caused because there is no data available in the `Scanner` object `sc`. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next().
Also, before calling `Scanner.next()`, you should always check if there is any data available using the `Scanner.hasNext()` method. i.e. `sc.hasNext()` in your case.

Comment: actually what i was trying to implement was that when only a user presses enter or some key then he will be directed to the next page. This also gives the user som time to view the current page. How to do that?

Comment: You cannot do that in a jsp. All your java code in the jsp is executed  to create the jsp. Once the jsp is rendered, the java code will not run. You might have to do what you intend to by using a ajax call(to check credentials) and a javascript 'alert' to get user confirmation before moving to the welcome page.